# format time in hours and minutes javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have the following row in my database in rails.

```
time: 10:00:00
```

In my javascript code, I call the data from the database and time is returned in   in this format '2000-01-01T10:00:00.000Z'.  Time set in database is 10:00:00.

How do i get the time in HH:MM format in javascript.

If i do this,

```
var time = 2000-01-01T10:00:00.000Z;
console.log(time.getHours());
```

i get an error. any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you can use a library, I recommend checking out `moment.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your time to a Date. Right now, it's just a string, so that is why you're getting "undefined is not a function" as your error.

```
var time = new Date('2000-01-01T10:00:00.000Z');
console.log(time.getHours() + ':' + time.getMinutes());
```